Custom merge driver for Json files in a maven
Hi all I am looking to create a custom merge driver for JSON files, this needs to be a custom driver as files will need to be handled differently depending on their content.
I have the following (likely optimistic) requirements:

needs to be stored in a corporate repository so ideally a maven stored java application
performance isn't to big an issue as this will only be ran locally on newish hardware
This will need to work on Windows and mac machines.

My hope is to have a java application I can set up as a dependency for my main application which can maintain the driver versions via the maven dependency config.
My question is how to trigger a call to a maven dependency from the .gitconfig, can I just point to the .m2 repo and follow the class path/folder structure or is there a better way?
I could be way off the mark and there is an easy way to do this I'm missing, or at least I hope so :)
Let me know if more info is required.
I have looked into the git-json-merge available on github and that is close to what I need but I don't want to be installing node.js on everyone's system. it also doe not meet my requirement of handling each document type differently.
I could also package up a node driver as a .exe and have everyone add it to their repo with a line in the .gitignore however this would have an issue where any updates would be auto delivered to the teams members.
